# org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, nginx

I am getting this error

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

I have an app https://test.com where I make a call to backend server to retrieve files from cloud storage like amazon s3. The backend call is `https://backend.com/api/getFile`

example of spring boot controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/getFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllFules(@RequestBody String test){
        try{
            //some code
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("ok", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("not ok", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

The backend server has a nginx running which routes to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

The client http code is like this in angular

```
$http({
            url: 'https://www.backend.com/api/getFiles',
            method: "POST",
            data: auth.profile['email']
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(" post success get files");



        },
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log("post failed get files");

        })
```

Comment: Are you sure the server/endpoint supports HTTPS?  Can you try and change it to HTTP.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when i was trying to call https://localhost:7002 (weblogic) to http://localhost:8080 (tomcat).

You need to enable SSL in both servers.if you are using two servers. because as i see, your http://127.0.0.1:8080/ is not ssl enabled server.